# How to graph $Abs(x) +Abs(x+1)$

Tags: functions, absolute-value

As I'm trying to graph this function on desmos which is a graphing calculator to verify my answer, there is a coordinate of (-0.5,1). The problem is I get every other whole coordinate EXCEPT that one despite trying the question multiple ways.

I'm mainly going about using the piecewise strategy

Comment: I do not understand what your question is. :)

Comment: Don't worry about Desmos – graphing calculators are not always accurate. How about you show us what you have graphed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f(x) = |x|+|x+1|=\begin{cases} -x -(x+1) & \forall x\in(-\infty,-1) \\-x +(x+1) &\forall x\in [-1,0) \\ x+x+1& \forall x\in [0,\infty)
\end{cases} =\begin{cases} -2x -1 & \forall x\in(-\infty,-1) \\1 &\forall x\in [-1,0) \\ 2x+1& \forall x\in [0,\infty)
\end{cases} $

So you'll get $1$ for all $x$ lying in the range $[-1,0]$

Answer (score 2):

Here's the plot.  What's the problem?

[image: |x|, |x+1|, |x| + |x+1|]

Comment: I'm not able to get the flat part of the graph shown there

Comment: From the graph above you should be able to see for $x$ between -1 and 0 the function is just $y = 1$, because for $x \leqslant -1$ then $|x+1| = x+1$ and $|x| = -x$ giving you $y = -x+x+1 = 1$

Answer (score 2):

Good question.

- You're using the piecewise strategy, which sounds like you've noted that $\mathrm{abs}(x)$ behaves like the function $f(x)=x$ when $x>0$ and like the function $f(x)=-x$ when $x<0$.
- You also know that $\mathrm{abs}(x+1)$ behaves like the function $f(x)=x+1$ when $x+1 > 0$, and behaves like the function $f(x) = -(x+1)$ when $x+1 < 0$.

  (In other words, the two conditions are when $x > -1$ and when $x < -1$.)
- The conditions we've collected so far are: $x>0$ and $x<0$, and $x<-1$ and $x>-1$. This divides the space into three chunks:
  $$\qquad\qquad\qquad\leftarrow \underset{-1}{|} \qquad\qquad\qquad  \underset{0}{|}\rightarrow \qquad\qquad\qquad $$
- Your function is $F(x) = \mathrm{abs}(x) + \mathrm{abs}(x-1)$.

  - In the first region, $x<-1$ and $x<0$, so it behaves like $F(x) = -x + -(x+1) = -2x-1$.
  - In the second region, $x>-1$ but $x<0$, so it behaves like $F(x) = x + -(x+1) = -1$.
  - In the third region, $x>-1$ and $x>0$, so it behaves like $F(x) = x + (x+1) = 2x+1$.
- The point $x=-0.5$ falls in the second region, because $x>-1$ and $x<0$. Therefore, for your function, $$F(-0.5) = (-0.5) + -(-0.5+1) = -0.5 - 0.5 = -1.$$

Comment: You took abs ( x-1 ) it was (x+1) however I understand the concept thank you

Comment: I used your strategy but I keep on getting when x= -0.5 y = 0 , you used |x- 1 | it's supposed to be |x+1|

Comment: @Harneet899 Fixed.